# How to show timelist in dropdown using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I want to show a timelist dropdown for interval of 30 minutes and based on the date. If the date is today and past the time then the past time will be disabled. If the date is not today then it will show all the timelist.

```js
 let $select = jQuery("#s_time");
    
        for (let hr = 8; hr < 22; hr++) {
    
        let hrStr = hr.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":";
    
        let val = hrStr + "00";
        $select.append('<option val="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
    
        val = hrStr + "30";
        $select.append('<option val="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>')
    
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <select name="s_time" id="s_time" class="form-control bmg-hrs-mins-input">
     </select>
    </div>
```

I expect the time that has been past will be disabled if the date is today and if it is not today then it will show all the timelist.

Comment: where is your date attribute?

Comment: do you want to enable the time picker only for the future dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `disable` the options conditionally. Try the following:

```js
let $select = $("#s_time");
for (let hr = 8; hr < 22; hr++) {

  let hrStr = hr.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":";

  let val = hrStr + "00";

  $select.append('<option val="' + val + '" ' + (new Date().getHours() >= hr ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '') + '>' + val + '</option>');

  val = hrStr + "30";
  $select.append('<option val="' + val + '" ' + (new Date().getHours() > hr || (new Date().getHours() >= hr && new Date().getMinutes() > 30) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '') + '>' + val + '</option>')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <select name="s_time" id="s_time" class="form-control bmg-hrs-mins-input"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly we need to compare the given date with today's date.

**Javascript Code**

```
var GivenDate = '2019-06-20';
var CurrentDate = new Date();
GivenDate = new Date(GivenDate);

if(GivenDate > CurrentDate){
   // enable select field 
     $('#s_time').prop('disabled', false);
}else{
   // disable select field 
    $('#s_time').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

I hope this helps! :)